# ADAL iOS: How to get credentials from iOS for later use on a server

Tags: ios, adal

I'm looking for a way for a user to log in with the [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library for iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) (what a name!), but pass the credentials to my backend server so that my backend server can make requests to the Office365 API on behalf of the user periodically. After initial authentication, the iOS app never needs to access Office365 or other Microsoft resources directly; the server handles all the communication with Microsoft's services.

From painfully digging through .NET code on the [WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet) example, it appears that the officially sanctioned process is:

1. Register 2 Active Directory applications under the same tenant, one for the server app and one for the native app. Add the server app in the client app's 'permissions to other applications' configuration.
2. Get the user's access token on iOS, then send it to the server
3. The server can then exchange the native app access token for a server app access token and make requests on behalf of the user whenever it wants

I'm hung up on how to do #3. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to exchange an access token from a native client application for an access token for a web application. I'm sure the [Active Directory Authentication Library for .NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) has the answer buried somewhere in it, but I haven't been able to find it. Has anyone had any luck with this flow?

Comment: FYI, our solution at the moment is to register a single server app, use a [modified version of ADALiOS](https://github.com/honestwork/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc.git) that exposes the method that gets the authorization code (`requestCodeByResource:`), then send the authorization code back to the server to be exchanged for an access token on the server. This works even if it's [not the officially sanctioned way](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/279).